# How can I get an html5 page to render in MFC

Tags: html, mfc

I need to render an HTML5 page with jQuery in a CHtmlView in an MFC application. 
The page renders rather pathetically, and I get a syntax error when it gets to the jquery script tag.

I've tried the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

It did nothing. I even upped the MSHTML browser version to 11 in the registry and get the same syntax error. I really do not want to go back to IE6-style javascript. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the meta tag does solve the issue. What I didn't realize was that my html view was running in a frameset, and the directive is ignored in a frame of a frameset. Does anyone here even remember framesets? Anyway, adding this line and removing the frameset was the answer:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the correct browser Emulation for your application this will not work.

Please read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So create an entry for your application in FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and set the Version to 11000!